# mysql - selecting groups and users all in same query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following two tables 'USERS' and 'GROUPS':

```
USERS 
-id
-name
-groupid

GROUP 
-id
-name
```

I'd like to return all users along with their group's name and group id. It should be an outer join on group id field correct?

Comment: Are all users assigned to exactly one group?  I believe you need an outer join if you also want users returned where users.groupid is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` between `users` and `groups` so that users who are not in a group still show up in the result set, but with group name and id NULL:

```
SELECT 
    a.*,
    b.name AS group_name
FROM
    users a
LEFT JOIN
    `group` b ON a.group_id = b.id
```

Side note: Ensure that you're encasing the table name `group` in backticks because it is a reserved keyword.

The result-set should look something like:

```
id       |       name       |       group_id       |       group_name
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        |       John       |       5              |       ThisIsGroup5
3        |       Tim        |       3              |       ThisIsGroup3
6        |       NotInGroup |       NULL           |       NULL
```

Changing `LEFT` to `INNER` in the above query would INNER JOIN the two tables and exclude the user "NotInGroup" from the result-set.

Answer (score 2):

A simple INNER JOIN should be enough:

```
SELECT `USERS`.*, `GROUP`.name AS group_name
FROM `USERS`, `GROUP`
WHERE `USERS`.groupid = `GROUP`.id
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to look at the `JOIN` statement

Doing this from my phone, so pardon any moderately incorrect syntax, but something a long the lines of

Edit: other guy's syntax is better. It's too early here